# How to have two mat date pickers with different dates only month and year

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to have a two matdatepicker, from date and to date that only show month and year.
I followed https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview.

I have two date pickers but when I select a month and year on one, the other will be updated with same values(vice versa).

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDateDP" 
 placeholder="From Date" #fromDate
              [formControl]="date" name="fromDate">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDateDP"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #fromDateDP
              startView="multi-year"
              (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
              (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, fromDateDP)"
              panelClass="example-month-picker">
              </mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="col-50">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="toDateDP" placeholder="To Date" #toDate
                name="todate" [formControl]="date">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDateDP" class="md-datepicker-input-container"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #toDateDP
              startView="multi-year"
              (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
              (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, toDateDP)"
              panelClass="example-month-picker">
              </mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**TS Snippet**

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};    

export class DatepickerViewsSelectionExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
  }

  chosenMonthHandler(normalizedMonth: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonth.month());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }
}
```

How can I alter my code where if I select a matdatepicker on fromDate it will not update matdatepicker on toDate?

**Attempt**

Updated HTML toDate

**HTML**

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDateDP" class="md-datepicker-input-container"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #toDateDP
                  startView="multi-year"
                  (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandlerTo($event)"
                  (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandlerTo($event, toDateDP)"
                  panelClass="example-month-picker">
                  </mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
```

and in the component, I added chosenYearHandlerTo, and chosenMonthHandlerTo functions which is simliar to code above.

As you can see in sample picture both date pickers are updated with same values.

[image: Example Issue]

Comment: Try using different form controls for each date picker. Right now you are using `date` for both of them, and they are synced to the same value.

Comment: @MattNienow Thank you, Can't believe I missed that.